# Script to kill/restart rdpclip?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, clipboard

We use remote desktop a lot (XP to Server 2003), and people are having trouble with the clipboard randomly not working. After ensuring that all drives were selected for the remote connection, and rdpclip was killed/restarted, the clipboard works again.

I'm wondering if there's a way I can automate this process for the users so I don't have to manually kill and restart rdpclip every time it stops working for someone. Could I write a batch file that would kill rdpclip and restart it only for the current user? Is there a better solution?

Comment: thx, works fine!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
taskkill /f /im rdpclip.exe /fi "username eq %USERNAME%" && rdpclip
```

Answer (score 3):

To restart it in a `.bat`:

```
taskkill /f /im rdpclip.exe /fi "username eq %USERNAME%"
start rdpclip.exe
exit
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to make it(batch) wait a second between `taskkill` and `start`. Without it i faced a problem several times: system had not yet killed the proccess by the time the `start` command came in. So the new proccess didn't start, and the old got killed. Result: no rdpclip.exe at all =(

```
cls
taskkill /F /FI "USERNAME eq %username%" /IM rdpclip.exe
ping -n 1 -w 1000 1.1.1.1>nul
start rdpclip.exe
```

Save as .bat.

Comment: I was wondering why `ping` is used instead of `timeout` and looked around. If anyone else is curious; from https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html: “A delay can also be produced by the PING command with a loopback address, there is a delay of 1 second between each consecutive ping.

In tests PING consumes less processor time than Sleep.exe or Timeout.exe, this allows other processes to run in the background.”